# mongoose nothing happens when i try to insert

Tags: javascript, node.js, mongodb, mongoose

i have the following `schema`:

```
module.exports = function (mongoose) {
    var playlist = mongoose.Schema({
        title: String,
        artist: String,
        album: String,
        time: Date
    });

    return mongoose.model('playlist', playlist);
};
```

And then i have the following code:

```
var PlayListModel = require('./schemas/playlist.schema.js')(mongoose);
musicItem.time = new Date();
mongoose.models.playlist().save(musicItem).then(function (result) {
    mongoose.find({title: musicItem.title}, function (err, doc) {
        if(!err)
        {
            console.log(doc);
        }
        else
        {
            console.log(err);
        }
    })
}, function (err) {
    console.log(err);
})
```

However there is no console message an no error only the following warning when i start the server:

```
`open()` is deprecated in mongoose >= 4.11.0, use `openUri()` instead, or set the `useMongoClient` option if using `connect()` or `createConnection()`. See http://mongoosejs.com/docs/connections.html#use-mongo-client
Mongoose: mpromise (mongoose's default promise library) is deprecated, plug in your own promise library instead: http://mongoosejs.com/docs/promises.html
```

Can anyone tell me what ive done wrong?

Comment: Note, the callback for `find` comes back with an array of documents, not one object (so `docs` instead of `doc`) And I don't think `mongoose` itself has a `find` method ([PlayListModel does](http://mongoosejs.com/docs/queries.html) however).

Answer (score 1, accepted):

You can try following code:

```
 var PlayListModel = require('./schemas/playlist.schema.js')(mongoose);

 musicItem.time = new Date()
 var playListModel = new PlayListModel(musicItem);
 playListModel.save( (err, playList) => { 

     // save data in playList

     // find result
     PlayListModel.find({title: musicItem.title}, (err2, result) => {
         // result
     });
 ));
```